# FieldValidators and Visual Web Part (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, validation, web-parts

I have a visual web part (a simple form) with RequiredFieldValidators. But a problem has occured since the field validators block editing of the page. When i press Edit Page in Sharepoint it starts to load then the validators fire and the javascript is stopped.

I found a solution but i cant get it to work.

Like this

```
public override void CreateChildControls()
{
    if(SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
        ((UserControl)_ctl).EnableValidators(false);
    ((UserControl)_ctl).EnableValidators(true);
}

//But the _ctl does not exit i only have 

Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
```

A litte advice would help this sharepoint noob a great deal.

The form is just Labels, Inputs, a button, updatepanel and requiredFieldValidators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just set the ValidationGroup for the validators and button? Like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

The validators should only fire when the button is pressed.

Comment: Hi. Since you did use the ValidationGroup soultion, please could you mark my response as the answer? Cheers. Howard

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your configuration - I tested this configuration and the required field validators definitely don't block editing on the page.  Do you want to post your page and your code behind?   Might help to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I found another solution, i had not put my validators into a validation group. Did that and bound that to the submit button and had used <asp:RequiredFieldValidators instead of SharePoint:InputFieldValidatorS